# How can I override a variable's type which has already declared inside lib.dom.d.ts?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write an ambient definition for a js framework which runs on browser, but I found that this framework overrides StorageManager and makes it becomes a static object.

This is the js code:

```
function StorageManager() {
    throw new Error('This is a static class');
}

StorageManager.save = function(savefileId, json) {
    //omitted
};

StorageManager.load = function(savefileId) {
    //omitted
};
```

Here is the declare code I copied from [here](https://github.com/AsterAtwood/rmmv.d.ts/blob/ca1d049a6e22e150dd6c530b3609025d8451d3bb/src/rpg_managers.d.ts#L442), my work is based on this project:

```
/**
 * StorageManager
 *
 * The static class that manages storage for saving game data.
 */
interface StorageManagerStatic {
    save(savefileId: number, json: string): void;
    load(savefileId: number): string;
    //other methods omitted.
}
declare var StorageManager: StorageManagerStatic;
```

But since StorageManager is declared at lib.dom.d.ts, vscode hints me on the last line that `Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'StorageManager' must be of type '{ new (): StorageManager; prototype: StorageManager; }', but here has type 'StorageManagerStatic'.`

I want to redeclare StorageManager's type to StorageManagerStatic, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Sometimes globals are declared in a way that allows extension  (such as the `Boolean` constructor for example. Sometimes they are not. `StorageManager` is in the category of defined not to be extended, since its type is declared inline instead of being a separate interface which you could extends.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Does this mean that what I want is not achievable? I don't want to extend StorageManager, but to replace it with my own interface  completely.

Comment: Not unless you are willing to remove the default lib ( there are compiler options for this) and replace it with a custom version of it

Answer (score 0):

According to [Titian Cernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir), I can't achieve this without modifying TypeScript's built-in `lib.dom.d.ts`.

Instead of redeclare built-in variable, I came out a workaround like this:

```
interface Window{
    StorageManager: StorageManagerStatic;
}
```

when using StorageManager, I need to write this: 
`window.StorageManager.load()`

Very inelegant, but I can't found a better solution.